# Parsing csv file from a button press using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have the following url https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=IBD which I want to parse data from

(I found nothing against scraping in their terms), the site is public, there's an 'export' button to download some historic data in csv, I want to automate downloading the file content with python.

I tried many options in the past day, this is my recent one

def parse_history():
url = "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=IBD"

```
web_page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.content, "html.parser")

form = soup.find('form', id='side-export-search-by-year-form')

download_url = form.get('action')

form_data = {}
for input_field in form.find_all('input'):
    form_data[input_field.get('name')] = input_field.get('value')

csrf_token = get_csrf_token(url)
form_data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = csrf_token

response = requests.post(f"{url}{download_url}", data=form_data)

# Save the downloaded file
with open('history.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

and I get error 403 with "invalid security token" message in the HTML value.

Any ideas? I prefer not to use selenium.

Comment: I also tried using headers and pass "Browser" alike agent but it did not help

Comment: With curl it seems to work, I'm confused

Comment: Your script is incomplete. Could you add the rest of it to have a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to scrape? Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: I dont understand what info is missing, I said the button I'm trying to extract data from (mimick pressing him and getting its response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    base_url = "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"
    url = f"{base_url}/?term=IBD"
    with requests.Session() as s:
        web_page = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.content, "html.parser")
        form = soup.find("form", id="side-export-search-by-year-form")
        action_url = form.get("action")
        download_url = f"{base_url}{action_url}"
        form_data = {}

        for input_field in form.find_all("input"):
            form_data[input_field.get("name")] = input_field.get("value")
            
        form_data["term"] = "IBD"
        cookies = web_page.cookies
        cookies.update({"pm-iosp": ""})

        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.63",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8",
            "origin": "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov",
            "referer": "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=IBD",
            "sec-ch-ua": "'Chromium';v='110', 'Not A(Brand';v='24', 'Microsoft Edge';v='110'",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
            "sec-gpc": "1",
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "dnt": "1",
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=0"}
        
        response = requests.post(url=download_url, data=form_data, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, timeout=5)
        with open("history.csv", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have copy pasted almost all request headers. You were missing the exact payload and cookies.

Comment: Mind explaining why it works exactly? I see that 'download_url = f"{base_url}{action_url}"' is different than what I'd expect, this is without the term, also cookies and headers seem to be added, what was actually missing on my part? 

And many thanks for the answer! it works like a charm!

Comment: You were missing the exact payload, cookies, and headers. I've copy-pasted almost all request headers. As we were getting 403 error status so headers were required, though all may not be required. The form action URL wasn't accurate.

Comment: How you copied the request headers, dev-tools in chrome? I saw 4 requests sent per click

thanks for the explanation :D

Comment: Go to the network tab on dev-tools, click on any API request, and now go to the headers tab; you will see response and request headers. If you navigate to any API's request tab, you will see the payload if it has a payload.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @BenShmok, is it still unclear to you?

Comment: It is clear, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
import re

BASE_NCBI_URL = "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"
YEAR_COUNT_DATA_REGEX = r'yearCounts:\s*"\[(.*?)\]"'

def get_term_history_amount_stat(term: str):
    url = f"{BASE_NCBI_URL}?term={term}"

    output = subprocess.check_output(['curl', url])

    year_counts_pattern = r'yearCounts:\s*"\[(.*?)\]"'
    year_counts_match = re.search(year_counts_pattern, output.decode(), re.DOTALL)
    if year_counts_match:
        return eval(year_counts_match.group(1))
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Cant parse historical data for term {term}")
```

Implemented it with subprocess and curl, for some reason curl does not get any permission errors, it just less convenient to parse it but it works.